# ng-mouseenter and ng-mouseleave not working inside an ng-repeat loop

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, events, angular-directive

I have an angular ng-repeat that displays list items inside of an unordered list.  Within each list item, I have another unordered list of sub-items.  Inside each sub-item `<li>`, I have a div to display a name and a div to store a value.

I am trying to hook up the ng-mouseenter and ng-mouseleave attributes to the value div, but they aren't firing.  Even just trying to execute a console.log statement inside of the directives is not printing anything to the console.

I have no page load errors, everything displays on the page fine so angular is set up correctly, it's just ng-mouseenter and ng-mouseleave are not firing.

What do I have to do in order to get ng-mouseenter and ng-mouseleave to properly fire?

> index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/SkillsetController.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="mainApp">
    <div id="skillset" ng-controller="SkillsetController">
        <h2>{{title}}</h2>
        <div class="skillListContainer" id="skillListContainer">
            <ul class="skillCategoriesList">
                <li class="skillCategory" ng-repeat="category in skillsetCategories">
                    <h3>{{category.title}}</h3>
                    <ul class="skillsList">
                        <li class="skill" ng-repeat="skill in category.skills">
                            <div class="skillName">
                                <span>{{skill.name}}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="skill-value" data-skill-value="{{skill.level}}" 
                                ng-mouseenter="console.log('enter');" 
                                ng-mouseleave="console.log('leave');">
                                {{skill.level}}
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

> app.js

```
var app = angular.module("mainApp", []);
```

> SkillsetController.js

```
app.controller("SkillsetController", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
  $scope.title = "Skillset";
  $scope.skillsetCategories = [
    {
      "title": "Backend",
      "skills": [
        {
          "name": "Java",
          "level": 10
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Frontend",
      "skills": [
        {
          "name": "HTML",
          "level": 9
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Frameworks",
      "skills": [
        {
          "name": "jQuery",
          "level": 9
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Databases",
      "skills": [
        {
          "name": "MySQL",
          "level": 10
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
}]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ng-mouseenter` and `ng-mouseleave` work just fine in your code, just you can't call console.log in html directly, the functions you are using in your html template must be defined in your controller, try move console.log to your controller should resolve the problem.

index.html

```
<div class="skill-value" data-skill-value="{{skill.level}}"
  ng-mouseenter="mouseEnter()"
  ng-mouseleave="mouseLeave()">
  {{skill.level}}
</div>
```

controller:

```
$scope.mouseEnter = function(){
  console.log('enter');
};
$scope.mouseLeave = function(){
  console.log('leave');
};
```

Answer (score 1):

console.log() is not valid directly in the html
thats why you need to create those function to work

just change this add this function to your controller

```
  $scope.mouseEnter = function(){
    console.log("enter");
  };

  $scope.mouseLeave = function(){
    console.log("leave");
  };
```

and change this in the html

```
<div class="skill-value" data-skill-value="{{skill.level}}" 
                            ng-mouseenter="mouseEnter()" 
                            ng-mouseleave="mouseLeave()">
                            {{skill.level}}
 </div>
```

Here is a [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/i0bZ0ctirhf4m5QKQXmi?p=preview)